# Integral involving radicals

Tags: integration

Can anyone give some hint as to how to proceed in solving this integral:

$$
\int \frac{u}{\sqrt{R^{2}+r^{2}-2Rru}}\mathrm{d}u
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v=R^2+r^2-2Rru$.  It is simple to write $u$ and $du$ in terms of $v$ and $dv$.  You get $$\int\frac{A+Bv}{\sqrt{v}}dv.$$   Expand this out before integrating.

Comment: Gotcha !! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly different approach, using

$$\int\frac{f'}{\sqrt f}dx=2\sqrt f+C\;\;:$$

$$\int\frac{u}{\sqrt{R^2+r^2-2rRu}}du=-\frac1{2rR}\int\frac{(R^2+r^2-2rRu)'}{\sqrt{R^2+r^2-2rRu}}du=$$

$$=-\frac1{rR}\sqrt{R^2+r^2-2rRu}+C$$